# Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression using Date

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Dim myDate As Date

    myDate = CDate(Date)

SQL = " Select Count(PONumber) As OverDue from tblPO where POExpireDate < '" & myDate & "'"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```

Im running this code....at OpenRecordset its shows error...

> Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression.

What should i do now...why this error Coming?

Answer (score 1):

As `Date` returns the current date, all you need is to use `Date()` directly in the SQL:

```
SQL = "Select Count(PONumber) As OverDue from tblPO where POExpireDate < Date()"
```